# Condition for Selecting multiple columns and rows

Tags: mysql, sql

How would I do to select all videos that have upload_key
= host with cnn in upload_value and send = 0

```
+----------+---------+------------+--------------+
| video_id | meta_id | upload_key | upload_value |
+----------+---------+------------+--------------+
| 1        | 6       | host       | cnn          |
| 1        | 7       | send       | 0            |
+----------+---------+------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Add a few more rows of sample data. And also specify the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> select all videos that have upload_key = host with cnn in upload_value and send = 0

One method is aggregation and `having`:

```
select video_id
from t
where upload_key in ('host', 'send')
group by video_id
having sum( upload_key = 'host' and upload_value = 'cnn' ) > 0 and
       sum( upload_key = 'send' and upload_value = '0' ) > 0;
```

Comment: And how would I do to update. Update only the videos that host = cnn and send = 0

Comment: @BrunoAndrade . . . You properly asked this as a new question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55184261/update-table-using-condition-with-multiple-rows-and-columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1f31c083a319ccc66742c20a99fb24a7)**

```
select video_id
from tablename where (upload_key,upload_Value) =('host','cnn')
   and exists (select 1 from tablename where (upload_key,upload_Value)=('send','0'))
```

Comment: How would I update? Update send to 1 only where 'host' is equal to 'cnn'