# Update table using condition with multiple rows and columns

Tags: mysql, sql

How would you do to update send = 1 only where in the video_id where 'host' is equal to 'cnn'

```
+----------+---------+------------+--------------+
| video_id | meta_id | upload_key | upload_value |
+----------+---------+------------+--------------+
| 1        | 6       | host       | cnn          |
| 1        | 7       | send       | 0            |
+----------+---------+------------+--------------+
```

Comment: It was partially answered only part of the select missing part of the update. Resolve to divide the questions

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `join`:

```
update t join 
       t tc
       on t.video_id = tc.video_id and
          tc.upload_key = 'host' and
          tc.upload_value = 'cnn' 
    set t.upload_value = '1'
    where t.upload_key = 'send' and t.upload_value <> '1';
```

Comment: What would this 'tc' be ?? Would I join the table with her myself?

Comment: @BrunoAndrade . . . It is intended to be a table alias, and now it is.